# Loading a specific county dataset in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geocoding, tiger

I want to load a specific county dataset in PostGIS. I can load a state script using:

`SELECT loader_generate_script(ARRAY['CA'], 'linux');`

However, I want to load dataset only for Los Angeles County instead of whole California state for performance reason. Geocoding with whole of California data is slow. My assumption is geocoding would be faster if I have only 1 county to work with (I need only LA data).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is edit the generated script down to the county you want.

Take a look at our presentation where we describe the process:

http://www.postgis.us/Presentations/PGOpen2014_Session1.html#/5/5